# About supports-screens android

Tags: android

I published my first app last week, I wanted my app to work on all phones (or tablet with SMS) so `minSdkVersion="7"`.

In developer console/APK/ No Compatible devices don’t appear Samsung Galaxy SIII, however my app is not available (play Store) on Samsung Galaxy SIII (720 x 1280 pixels, 4.8 inches), I think that the problem could be on the Manifest file:

I have alternative drawables hdpi/ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi and I have layouts layout/ layout-small/ layout-large/ layout-xlarge.

I read in Android developers/ Filtering based on the App Manifest:

•   When the either the android: minSdkVersion or android: targetSdkVersion is set to 4 or higher, the default for all attributes is "true". In this way, the application is considered to support all screen sizes by default.

My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="false">…and the activitys.
```

I found this solution:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

The question: ¿Is supports-screens mandatory?  Or can I omit that (supports-screens) and after that will my app work on Galaxy SIII (720 x 1280 pixels, 4.8 inches)?

Please help me and excuse my bad English.

Comment: `minSdkVersion="7"` is obsolete: it's **less than the 0.1%** of the Market (as of 2014-03-04). And no, it's NOT mandatory, nor compulsory.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and for your advice, but unfortunately, some of my clients have old smartphones. 
I have tested my application in others galaxy S3(m0), Ace and s3 mini.
Do you know some other reason why a device is listed as compatible (console) but in the reality is not?

Comment: I'd recommend a minSdkVersion of **8**. Froyo (API 8) is still the **1.2%** of the market and GingerBread (API 9) is the **19%**. Eclair (API 7) is **under the 0.1%**, so you can goodbye it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `support-screens` tag is not mandatory in the manifest. Removing it will be the same as having them all set to `true`.

Also, I would suggest making the `minSdkVesion` at least 10. There is no reason to have it before that nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and for your advice, but unfortunately, some of my clients have old smartphones. 
I have tested my application in others galaxy S3(m0), Ace and s3 mini.
Do you know some other reason why a device is listed as compatible (console) but in the reality is not?

Comment: I'd recommend a minSdkVersion of **8**. Froyo (API 8) is still the **1.2%** of the market and GingerBread (API 9) is the **19%**. Eclair (API 7) is **under the 0.1%**, so you can goodbye it.